# Stroustrup's C++: exercise 6.2.3 Character types conversion won't work for me

Tags: c++

This example is supposed to write ten digits to cout, but I can't get it to work. I'm expecting it to print ten integers, but instead it's printing alpha characters.

What have I done wrong?

```
#include <iostream>


void digits()
{
    for (int i=0; i!=10; ++i)
        std::cout<<static_cast<char>('O'+i);
}

int main()
{

    digits();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What alpha characters exactly? Which compiler?

Comment: Oh, that should have been a '0' (zero) not an 'O' (capital latin letter O).

Comment: Ah, you and Jim must be right, but I'm missing something. I now see that he also wrote that if he left out static_cast<char> the output would have been 48, 49, etc, which is exactly what happens. I suppose I was expecting the alpha char O to be changed into its numeric equivalent, but obviously something else is happening here. Thanks guys. I am sure I will figure it out, but if you have an explanation that would be cool.

Comment: A `char` is actually a small integer type in addition to representing a character. Now, adding a `char` and an `int` has an `int` as result, which explains the numeric output. For that reason, the result is explicitly converted to a `char` using `static_cast`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::cout<<static_cast<char>('O'+i);
```

should be

```
std::cout<<static_cast<char>('0'+i);
```

(Numeral 0 rather than letter O).

Comment: hum. What you're saying works, but it doesn't make sense in the context of the example. He's saying that "character types are integral types so that arithmetic and bitwise logical operations apply." More to the point, he's saying the "character literal 'O' is converted to its integer value and i is added.

Comment: @TimElhajj: So, yes, you can do `'0'+i`, which is an arithmetic operation with `char` as one operand. As opposed to for example Pascal, where you have to do `ord('0') + i', where `ord` gives the ascii [or ebcdic, etc] of the character zero.

Comment: @TimElhajj What's wrong with that? In this case, the character `O` was being treated as a number, incremented by the value of i and then casted back into a character. The effect of this in a loop would be the printing of the alphabets starting with O since the numerical values of them are consecutive.

Comment: It's just the way it's written makes it hard to know if I don't understand the concept or if I've typed something wrong. He says that if he'd left out the static_cast(char) it would result in 48, 49 (as it does) rather than 0, 1, and so on, which it only does if I use a numeral (and not the character literal 'O' as he explicitly calls for). Ah, programming is hard. :)

Comment: Wait, I think I see what he means. The numerical representation of the character set for the number 0 is 48. So if I leave off the static_cast(char) and use the numeral zero, it starts at 48. Wow. It wasn't at all obvious to me that's what he meant from just reading, looking at it. Thanks people. And now I understand what Mats is saying. :)

Comment: @Tim: `'0'` IS a character literal.  The contrast is between `'0'` and `0`... both use the digit ZERO, not the letter O.  The difference is in the quotes.